# Video Transmitter/Receiver Books&Schematics

Tags: audio, radio, video, transmitter, receiver

I'm looking to build a video/audio or just video transmitter and receiver for use in robots. I'm primarily doing it as an excercise, but I'd love to be able to get a range of 100-200 meters. I'd love any books or other materials you would recommend on this topic or on radio design. I'm an EE student, but I'll read anything you can provide. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at commercial transmitters and the ICs involved. Then read the datasheets/application notes of those ICs. Usually you can learn a lot just from application notes.